# Get data automatically from anchor tag in Python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, anchor

I have a page with content like

```
<div class="entry">
  <p>some content></p>
   <a href="www.somelink.com">more</a>
</div>
```

in the main web page. I want to extract and display the data on clicking the link. I am using beautifulsoup in python3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display the content of the extracted url by using `mainpage` parameter.

```
    code = '''<div class="entry">
              <p>some content></p>
              <a href="www.somelink.com">more</a>
              </div>'''
    soup = BeautifulSoup(code, 'html.parser')
    divtag = soup.find('div', attrs={"class": "entry"})
    a_tags = divtag.find_all('a')
    for a in a_tags:
        url = a.get('href')
        response = requests.get(url)
        mainpage = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html5lib')
```

Comment: thank you for the code. what if i want to extract the content of a specific tag present on the new url eg there is another <div class="entry"><p>actual data</p></div> on the newly clicked link .

Answer (score 0):

working code
divtag = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "entry"})

```
   for a in divtag:
        a_tag = a.find('a')
        url = a_tag.get('href')
        response = requests.get(url)
        mainpage = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html5lib')
        divtag1 = mainpage.find('div', attrs={"class": "entry"})
        a_tag1 = divtag1.find('p')
        print(a_tag1.get_text())
```